# Error- Plot PDF and CDF Bokeh : unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, pdf, pandas, bokeh, cdf

I am trying to read a csv and calculate the PDF and CDF with Bokeh. I am getting error. The input file is `keyword` and `freq`. The distribution of the frequency is to plotted. The input below are few rows from more than 50k rows.

Input:

```
#sportsnews,8
#mashupradiomx,1
#arrestobama,2
#alemanha,1
#bizeskiden,1
#musicnews,4
#costumedesign,2
#champain,1
#pacer,1
#brunner,1
#fotoviajera,1
#itsjihadstupid,1
#lesdernierssurvivants,1
#sainsburycentre,1
#alanalwaysinourheart,1
#runinapp,1
#foroporlavida,1
#kidsday,1
#momentofart,2
```

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import scipy.special
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, vplot

df = pd.read_csv('keyword.csv', header = None)

df.columns = ['keyword','freq']

p5 = figure(title="Weibull Distribution (λ=1, k=1.25)", tools="save",
            background_fill_color="#E8DDCB")

lam, k = 1, 1.25

#measured = lam*(-np.log(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000)))**(1/k)
#hist, edges = np.histogram(measured, density=True, bins=50)

x = df['freq']
pdf = (k/lam)*(x/lam)**(k-1) * np.exp(-(x/lam)**k)
cdf = 1 - np.exp(-(x/lam)**k)

p5.quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:],
       fill_color="#036564", line_color="#033649")

p5.line(x, pdf, line_color="#D95B43", line_width=8, alpha=0.7, legend="PDF")
p5.line(x, cdf, line_color="white", line_width=2, alpha=0.7, legend="CDF")

p5.legend.location = "top_left"
p5.xaxis.axis_label = 'x'
p5.yaxis.axis_label = 'Pr(x)'

output_file('histogram.html', title="histogram.py example")

show(vplot(p5))
```

I want to plot both `line` plots only.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf_bokeh.py", line 21, in <module>
    pdf = (k/lam)*(x/lam)**(k-1) * np.exp(-(x/lam)**k)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

**Edit 1:** After changing `x=df['freq']` I am getting strange output. 
The full input file [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iip5sreqrlz1c6a/random_split_keyword.csv?dl=0)  The data is discrete in nature but still distribution plots do not look like the below output.

The output: This is not really any where close to what it should be.

[image]

Comment: what is `x` meant to be as you've defined it as `x = ['freq']`?

Comment: @EdChum `x` is the `freq` to be plotted

Comment: I assume you want x = df['freq']

Comment: But you assigned a list with a string to it and the error is telling you that you're trying to divide this by an int which is clearly an error, are you wanting `x=df['freq']`?

Comment: Let me try the `x=df['feq']`

Comment: Just a wild guess, is `df['freq']` un-sorted?

Comment: Ahh, now I see what you are trying to do. I would not use x=df['freq'] at all. Create a new array, with say `x = np.linspace(df['freq'].min(), df['freq'].max(), 100)`. This will sample your distribution at these `x` coordinates.

Comment: @oystein the data is un sorted

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the x-axis for the theoretical distribution, you do not want to sample this at `x=df['freq']`, but at some pretty looking coordinates. I downloaded your dataset and was able to get something sensible with:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100) # 100 points between 0 and 5
```

You could do some fancy statistics to figure out that most of the data is below 5.

Comment: If I am putting x=linespace(0,5,10) then where am I giving my inputs?